# What causes APNS token to change?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, token

Is there a difference between token lifetime on sandbox vs production?

I am locked into using a sandbox environment at the moment and am wondering what is causing my token to expire/reset.

I am not uninstalling the app nor updating the iOS version between apparent token expirations.

I do force close and background the app as part of dev/testing.

I am also using a VoIP certificate which I believe is valid for both production and sandbox.

The app being run on the iOS devices is built and pushed direct from Xcode.

---

What appears to be happening is the token gets changed sometime between when the app is no longer running on the receiving device and when it should be receiving the push notification. The app doesn't have a chance to run to update the token before then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not completely documented as to what invalidates an APNS token, the docs do mention:

> If the user restores backup data to a new device or computer, or reinstalls the operating system, the device token changes.

However, I imagine these aren't the only scenarios that cause a token to expire. What *is* documented is the fact that you should not cache the token but instead always pull it from the system if & when required.

See [Registering for Remote Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW2), specifically:

> Moreover, never cache a device token and give that to your provider; always get the token from the system whenever you need it. If your app has previously registered, calling registerForRemoteNotifications results in the operating system passing the device token to the delegate immediately without incurring additional overhead. Also note that the delegate method may be called any time the device token changes, not just in response to your app registering or re-registering.